# Migrate from apt lxc 3.0.3 to snap 4.0.9. Mount points problem

Tags: upgrade, zfs, lxc, lxd

I need to upgrade my Ubuntu from 18.04, and for this, I need to upgrade LXC/LXD to snap version. So, I ran: lxd.migrate and I got the following output:

```
=== Destination server
LXD version: 4.0.9
LXD PID: 7439
Resources:
  Containers: 1
  Images: 0
  Networks: 1
  Storage pools: 1
```

Although, my container and ZFS pool mount points are gone:

```
NAME                           USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
lxd                           10.9G  17.9G    19K  none
lxd/containers                10.9G  17.9G    19K  none
lxd/containers/cms            10.9G  17.9G  5.91G  none
lxd/custom                      24K  17.9G    24K  none
lxd/deleted                    120K  17.9G    24K  none
lxd/deleted/containers          24K  17.9G    24K  none
lxd/deleted/custom              24K  17.9G    24K  none
lxd/deleted/images              24K  17.9G    24K  none
lxd/deleted/virtual-machines    24K  17.9G    24K  none
lxd/images                      24K  17.9G    24K  none
```

Container after the migration was moved from `/var/lib/lxd/storage-pools/lxd/containers/cms` to `/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/containers/cms`. While zfs pool was moved from `/var/lib/lxd/disks/lxd.img` to `/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/disks/lxd.img`.

Could you help me with the commands I need to run to set new mount points?